# How to save indention format of file in Python

Tags: python

I am saving all the words from a file like so:

```
     sentence = " "
   fileName = sys.argv[1]
   fileIn = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
   for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
      for word in line.split(" "):
         sentence += word
```

Everything works okay when outputting it except the formatting.
I am moving source code, is there any way I can save the indention?

Comment: In what conditions, exactly, does the indentation disappear?

Comment: Lets say I am copying all the text from a .py file into one large string. I get the newline characters. However I do not get the indention.

Comment: I am posting the source code via  a POST to a webpage (mine). However when it gets copied over only the new lines carry over.

Comment: with the approach above it seems so. you split by " ", so newlines are preserved, the rest has gone ...

Comment: @robertd: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please update your question with new facts.  Make the question as clear and complete as possible so we can delete these silly comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `line.split()`, you remove all leading spaces.

What's wrong with just reading the file into a single string?

```
textWithIndentation = open(sys.argv[1], "r").read()
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you state, that you want to *move source code files*, why not just copy/move them?

```
import shutil
shutil.move(src, dest)
```

If you read source file,

```
fh = open("yourfilename", "r")
content = fh.read()
```

should load your file as it is (with indention), or not?

Answer (score 1):

Split removes all spaces:

```
>>> a="   a b   c"
>>> a.split(" ")
['', '', '', 'a', 'b', '', '', 'c']
```

As you can see, the resulting array doesn't contain any spaces anymore. But you can see these strange empty strings (''). They denote that there has been a space. To revert the effect of split, use `join(" ")`:

```
>>> l=a.split(" ")
>>> " ".join(l)
'   a b   c'
```

or in your code:

```
sentence += " " + word
```

Or you can use a regular expression to get all spaces at the start of the line:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^\s*', "   a b   c").group(0)
'   '
```